# Unable to deploy ear on Wildfly 9

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8, wildfly-9

I am facing un-expected issue in Wildfly server 9.0.1. some times server runs , some times it throws following error. I searched a lot, some forums saying remove the breakpoints, i tried that also, but no luck

```
19:05:01,953 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
("core-service" => "management"),
("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
19:05:01,991 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 105) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /pages
19:05:06,960 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@127cc34a for operation {"operation" => "add-deployer-chains","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1292)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

19:05:06,961 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@127cc34a for operation {"operation" => "add-deployer-chains","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
19:05:11,965 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler@5b91c037 for operation {"address" => [("core-service" => "management"),("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")],"operation" => "add","map-groups-to-roles" => undefined} at address [
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1307)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How large is your EAR in Mega Bytes, does it contain a large number of third party jars as well?

Comment: Hi, ear is not so big. Its just 100 MB in size.

Comment: That's considered rather large in size, I'll add an answer you can try - if it helps please feel free to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server is taking too long to boot and deploy.  Try increasing the deployment scanner time out and/or adjusting system property "jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout".

Changing the deployment scanner timeout as referenced here [Deployment Scanner configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Deployment+Scanner+configuration)

**Attribute:** deployment-timeout

**Type:** LONG
**Description:** Timeout, in seconds, a deployment is allows to execute before being canceled. The default is 60 seconds.

Also note, I did find these **after** I started looking for how to adjust things for you so they will help to explain things further.
[Wildfly 10 1 stopd deployment after deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203175/wildfly-10-1-stopd-deployment-after-deploying?rq=1) and [How to reduce the time taken for wildfly to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406360/how-to-reduce-the-time-taken-for-wildfly-to-deploy) My original source for the answer was gleamed from the JBoss Forums.

Comment: cannot found the property settings in Deployment Scanner configuration

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a timeout exception is simply a timeout exception.  Depending on the nature of the deployment you can increase the timeout and see if this helps.  e.g. increase the deployment-timeout setting from the default to 10 minutes (600 seconds).

edit standalone.xml and change the deployment-scanner to something like this.

```
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="600"/>

    </subsystem>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, I already added 10 mins in standalone.xml  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="600" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
        </subsystem>

Comment: I also tried with 1h, nothing changes.